# Java getting TCP IP address from PID

Tags: java, tcp

I have a small app in which I check if an application is running, If it's running I get the PID of the process and then try to get the IP address of the TCP connection it opens, But even with multiple different programs I always get `0.0.0.0:port` and never the actual IP address, opening resource monitor on windows it shows the correct IP. Manually running netstat in CMD also only gives me `0.0.0.0:port`.

Is there a way to get the correct IP as shown in resource monitor?

the command: `"netstat -an -p tcp -o"`
here is how I get it in java:

```
try {
            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = r.exec(appConstants.NETSTAT_COMMAND);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine = "";
            serverIPAddress = "";
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (inputLine.contains(appPIDNumber)) {
                    serverIPAddress = inputLine.substring(31, 54);
                    System.out.println("IP before edit: " + serverIPAddress);
                    if (serverIPAddress.equalsIgnoreCase("0.0.0.0:0")
                            || serverIPAddress.contains("0.0.0.0:0")
                            || serverIPAddress.equalsIgnoreCase("0.0.0.0")
                            || serverIPAddress.contains("0.0.0.0")
                            || serverIPAddress.equalsIgnoreCase("127.0.0.0")
                            || serverIPAddress.contains("127.0.0.0")
                            || serverIPAddress.equalsIgnoreCase("127.0.0.1")
                            || serverIPAddress.contains("127.0.0.1")
                            || serverIPAddress.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                        serverIPAddress = null;
                        System.out.println("IP ADDRESS FAIL");
                        break;
                    }
                    if (serverIPAddress.contains(":")) {
                        serverIPAddress = serverIPAddress.substring(0, serverIPAddress.lastIndexOf(":")).trim();
                        System.out.println("CORRECT IP ADDRESS: " + serverIPAddress);
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            LoggingUtils.LogExceptions(LoggingConstants.ERROR, e.toString());
        }
        return serverIPAddress;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

netstat will only show you foreign IP addresses for connections that are established, but not for connections that are still only listening locally. But it sounds like you are aware of this and are looking for an established connection.

My guess is that your problem might be caused by `inputLine.contains(appPIDNumber)`. Could it be that the appPIDNumber shows up in an earlier line? Maybe as a port number? You should be checking specifically whether the entry in the PID column matches your PID, not just any part of the line. Even if this is not causing your error right now, it still is a bug in your code that will make it fail randomly if the PID ever matches one of the listening ports in the beginning of the list.

Maybe try `if (inputLine.trim().endsWith(" "+appPIDNumber)) {` instead and see if that helps.

Comment: Note: I added a space into the " "+appPIDNumber to prevent matching "12345" if I'm looking for PID 2345.

Comment: Thank you, it makes perfectly sense, will fix it asap.

Comment: If that doesn't fix it, maybe post the PID you are looking at and the output you get from the netstat call so that we have a little more info to go by. ;)

Answer (score 0):

> the IP address of the TCP connection it opens

If you mean the TCP IP:port at which it listens, that's going to be 0.0.0.0:xxx unless the program has bound to a specific IP address as well as port, which isn't usual. But if the process is in the localhost you don't need it, you can use 127.0.0.1 for example. And if it's a server and you just to know whether it's running, just try to connect to it. You don't need all this.

If you mean a remote TCP IP:port to which it has connected, you're looking at the wrong line, or the wrong column in the right line.

If you mean something else again, please clarify.